# I want to create a new task in linux kernel module, How can i do that?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

Currently I tried to use syscalls.h but there is an error. (MODULE_LICENSE("GPL"); is included).

[image: ERROR of syscalls.h]

Tried also to use both proc_fs.h and internal.h but as I see now they are just some functions of editing the filesystem /proc.

I don't see how I can create a new task with this header, tried creating a directory and files in /proc and they don't appear in the command "ps aux".

Is there any way I can create a new task (process) from linux kernel module?

Comment: The real question is: what are you trying to accomplish by creating a task from kernel space? Are you sure that you need an actual userspace task and not just a kernel thread?

Comment: I am sure about that.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add both a [mre] and an explanation what you want to achieve by creating a task/process.

Comment: @Ori thing is, creating an userspace task is something that you very, very rarely need to do in kernel code. I would say *never* in case you are working on a kernel module. Explaining what you would need that for would help to answer your question, there are different kinds of solutions.

Comment: Have you considered `call_usermodehelper()`?

Comment: Are you looking for the `kthread_run` call?  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.2/source/include/linux/kthread.h#L42

Comment: Actually I tried to fork&exec before the kernel object and I succeed creating the task but I need help sending it to the user, i can see the task in (ps aux) but my pid is not the task's pid, any help from even if its kernel mode and even user mode.